# how to display HTML in a UITextView

Tags: html, objective-c, cocoa-touch

essetially I just want formatted HTML rendered in the UITextView, should I be using the undocumented `setContentToHTMLString`? I feel that I should not be using that, I have tried it, but the text (after being rendered as HTML) does not scroll properly, which is why I suspect its not documented...

Should I just use a UIWebView? Can I just pass it arbitrary HTML and expect it to render it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can display arbitrary HTML in a `UIWebView` using `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` (see [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadHTMLString:baseURL:)).